# CheckedComboBoxEdit is created but cannot be used

Tags: winforms, devexpress, checkedlistbox, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm trying to add a `CheckedComboBoxEdit` to a `GridView` using `WinForms` and `devexpress`. This is what I got for now:

```
using (var _db = new DB())
{
    var isemirleri = _db.IsEmris.AsQueryable();
    var oalist = _db.OperasyonAksakliks.AsQueryable();

    gcIsEmirleri.DataSource = 
     (from i in isemirleri
      select new {
          ID = i.isEmriId,
          İşEmriNo = i.isEmriNo,
          Aksaklık = string.Join(",", 
              oalist
              .Where(o => o.operasyonId == i.Operasyons.FirstOrDefault().operasyonId)
              .Select(o => o.Durus.durusAdi).ToList())
      }).ToList();


    gvIsEmirleri.BeginUpdate();

//------------------------ THIS LINE -------------------------------------\\
    //DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Aksaklık", typeof(string));
//------------------------ THIS LINE -------------------------------------\\
    GridColumn column = gvIsEmirleri.Columns["Aksaklık"];
    column.Caption = "Aksaklık";
    column.Name = "Aksaklık";

    gvIsEmirleri.EndUpdate();

    RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit chk= new RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit();
    chk.Items.Clear();  
    foreach (Durus d in _db.Durus.Where(q => q.aksaklikMi == true))
        chk.Items.Add(new ListItem(d.durusId, d.durusAdi));
    chk.EditValueChanged += new EventHandler(chk_EditValueChanged);
    gvIsEmirleri.Columns["Aksaklık"].ColumnEdit = chk;
}
```

It successfully shows the present `Operasyons` with commas between and `CheckedComboBoxEdit`s can be seen on the grid (it shows the small button at the right of the cell).

However, the list of elements don't show up when I click on the cell. I debugged the project and observed that `chk` is set up correctly and holds the `Items` as meant to be.

If I de-comment the line I marked as `THIS LINE` and don't add `Aksaklık` to `gcIsEmirleri.DataSource` it successfully adds the list and it can be used properly, I can add the checked elements to the related database table, but I cannot see the changes in the view. By that I mean I cannot see the selected elements, as string combined or as checked in the line.

What am I doing wrong or what can I do else to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `Aksaklık` must be created once. Adding a new `GridColumn` and assigning `DataSource` causes the program not to work properly.

So I created a new column while assigning `DataSource`, named `TempColumn`, set it's visible to false. After that I added the `GridColumn` and do the operations as in the code in the question. After that I used `UnboundType` and get the needed string from `TempColumn`:

```
column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
column.UnboundExpression = "[TempColumn]";
```